# Pytest mocker patch - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, pyarrow

I am having what I believe to be a common issue in using mock patching in that I can not figure out the *right thing* to patch.

I have two questions that I am hoping for help with.

1. Thoughts on how to fix the specific issue in the below example
2. And possibly most-importantly pro-tips/pointers/thoughts/suggestions on how to best troubleshoot the "which thing do I patch" question.  The problem I'm having is, without a full understanding of how patching works, I really dont even know what I should be looking for and find myself playing a guessing game.

An example using `pyarrow` that is currently causing me pain:

#### mymodule.py

```
import pyarrow

class HdfsSearch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fs = self._connect()

    def _connect(self) -> object:
        return pyarrow.hdfs.connect(driver="libhdfs")

    def search(self, path: str):
        return self.fs.ls(path=path)
```

#### test_module.py

```
import pyarrow
import pytest

from mymodule import HdfsSearch

@pytest.fixture()
def hdfs_connection_fixture(mocker):
    mocker.patch("pyarrow.hdfs.connect")
    yield HdfsSearch()

def test_hdfs_connection(hdfs_connection_fixture):
    pyarrow.hdfs.connect.assert_called_once() # <-- succeeds

def test_hdfs_search(hdfs_connection_fixture):
    hdfs_connection_fixture.search(".")
    pyarrow.hdfs.HadoopFileSystem.ls.assert_called_once() # <-- fails
```

#### pytest output:

```
$ python -m pytest --verbose test_module.py
=========================================================================================================== test session starts ============================================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.0.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0 -- /home/bbaur/miniconda3/envs/dev/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/user1/work/app
plugins: cov-2.7.1, mock-1.10.4
collected 2 items

test_module.py::test_hdfs_connection PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                          [ 50%]
test_module.py::test_hdfs_search FAILED                                                                                                                                                                                              [100%]

================================================================================================================= FAILURES =================================================================================================================
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_hdfs_search _____________________________________________________________________________________________________________

hdfs_connection_fixture = <mymodule.HdfsSearch object at 0x7fdb4ec2a610>

    def test_hdfs_search(hdfs_connection_fixture):
        hdfs_connection_fixture.search(".")
>       pyarrow.hdfs.HadoopFileSystem.ls.assert_called_once()
E       AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called_once'

test_module.py:16: AttributeError
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're not calling the assert on the Mock object, this is the correct assert:

`hdfs_connection_fixture.fs.ls.assert_called_once()`

**Explanation:**

When you access any attribute in a Mock object it will return another Mock object.

Since you patched `"pyarrow.hdfs.connect"` you've replaced it with a Mock, let's call it Mock A. Your `_connect` method will return that Mock A and you'll assign it to `self.fs`.

Now let's break down what's happening in the `search` method when you call `self.fs.ls`.

`self.fs` returns your Mock A object, then the `.ls` will return a different Mock object, let's call it Mock B. In this Mock B object you're doing the call passing `(path=path)`.

In your assert you're trying to access `pyarrow.hdfs.HadoopFileSystem`, but it was never patched. You'll need do the assert on the Mock B object, which is at `hdfs_connection_fixture.fs.ls`

**What to Patch**

If you change your import in `mymodule.py` to this `from pyarrow.hdfs import connect` your patch will stop working.

Why is that?

When you patch something you're changing what a `name` points to, not the actual object.

Your current patch is patching the name `pyarrow.hdfs.connect` and in mymodule you're using the same name `pyarrow.hdfs.connect` so everything is fine.

However, if you use `from pyarrow.hdfs import connect` mymodule will have imported the real `pyarrow.hdfs.connect` and created a reference for it with the name `mymodule.connect`.

So when you call `connect` inside `mymodule` you're accessing the name `mymodule.connect`, which is not patched.

That is why you would need to patch `mymodule.connect` when using from import.

I'd recommend using `from x import y` when doing this kind of patching. It makes it more explicit what you're trying to mock and the patch will be limited to that module only, which can prevent unforeseen side-effects.

Source, this section in the Python documentation: [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id5)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Can you please update your answer to address item #2 as well so that people like me, without a full understanding of what mocking and patching is and how it works under the covers, can have a sense of how you approached this?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer and add something regarding what to patch. I left it once since you patched the correct thing, so it seemed to me you were confused regarding the the Mock object works.

Comment: Were you able to understand it now?

Comment: This solves an issue i had that chatGPT didn't realize. Grateful ‍♂️

Answer (score 4):

To understand how patching works in python let's first understand the import statement.

When we use `import pyarrow` in a module (mymodule.py in this case) it does two operations :

1. It searches for the `pyarrow` module in `sys.modules`
2. It binds the results of that search to a name(`pyarrow`) in the local scope.
   By doing something like: `pyarrow = sys.modules['pyarrow']`

*NOTE: `import` statements in python doesn't execute code. The import statement brings a name into local scope. The execution of code happens as a side-effect only when python can't find a module in sys.modules*

So, to patch *pyarrow* imported in mymodule.py **we need to patch the `pyarrow` name present in the local scope of mymodule.py**

```
patch('mymodule.pyarrow', autospec=True)
```

**test_module.py**

```
import pytest
from mock import Mock, sentinel
from pyarrow import hdfs

from mymodule import HdfsSearch


class TestHdfsSearch(object):
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='function')
    def setup(self, mocker):
        self.hdfs_mock = Mock(name='HadoopFileSystem', spec=hdfs.HadoopFileSystem)
        self.connect_mock = mocker.patch("mymodule.pyarrow.hdfs.connect", return_value=self.hdfs_mock)

    def test_initialize_HdfsSearch_should_connect_pyarrow_hdfs_file_system(self):
        HdfsSearch()

        self.connect_mock.assert_called_once_with(driver="libhdfs")

    def test_initialize_HdfsSearch_should_set_pyarrow_hdfs_as_file_system(self):
        hdfs_search = HdfsSearch()

        assert self.hdfs_mock == hdfs_search.fs

    def test_search_should_retrieve_directory_contents(self):
        hdfs_search = HdfsSearch()
        self.hdfs_mock.ls.return_value = sentinel.contents

        result = hdfs_search.search(".")

        self.hdfs_mock.ls.assert_called_once_with(path=".")
        assert sentinel.contents == result
```

**Use context managers to patch built-ins**

```
def test_patch_built_ins():
    with patch('os.curdir') as curdir_mock:  # curdir_mock lives only inside with block. Doesn't lives outside
        assert curdir_mock == os.curdir
    assert os.curdir == '.'
```